# Post in asp.net with AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I need to execute a post request and send an ID with it as data. my request reaches my code-behind but does not come with it.

in the code-behind `birdID` is empty.

in my network I see that `{birdID: "1"}` is send wit it

Ajax code:

```
 $(".AddToBird").click(function () {

        var bird = $(this).val();
        console.log(bird);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddBird")',
            data: '{birdID: "' + bird + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
                alert("Data has been added successfully.");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Code-behind(C#.net)

```
public IActionResult AddBird(string birdID)
    {
        birdCountModel newBird = new birdCountModel();

        newBird.birdID = int.Parse(birdID);
        newBird.userID = 1;

        _birdRepository.AddBird(newBird);

        return Content("5");
    }
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: oh yeah forgot to update, the code behind should be a Jsonresult, not an IActionresult!